# How do I view an image in dotnet interactive?

Tags: .net-core, f#, jupyter

I would like to view an image interactively in F# jupyter notebook similarly to how I can do this in python:

```py
from PIL import Image

Image.open("image.png")
```

and that shows an image.

Is there a straightforward way to do this?

EmguCV, OpenCVSharp and ImageSharp all don't work together with the plotting libraries like Plotly.NET or XPlot to provide this functionality so I can't get something like matplotlib's `pyplot.imshow`.

Comment: I've not used jupyter myself https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/net-core-with-juypter-notebooks-is-here-preview-1/ gives examples of displaying images using the HTML output API's

Comment: `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("start", pathToImage)` will open image with default application

Comment: @tranquillity Using the `display` function with html for a `<img>` with a base64 encoded source sounds like it could work but that's not straightforward.

Comment: @JL0PD I want to display the image within the interactive environment/notebook.

Answer (score 0):

In a notebook, you can display an image like this:

```
#!fsharp

// Load iamge
let data = File.ReadAllBytes("E:\\Downloads\\myImage.png");
// Convert so we can display it as HTML
let b64 = Convert.ToBase64String(data);
HTML($"<img src=\"data:image/png;base64,{b64}\"></img>") // last call without ; gets displayed
// Alt, this one has a semicolon: 
// display(HTML($"<img src=\"data:image/png;base64,{b64}\"></img>"));
```